# Measure which Alexa utterances are used

Tags: analytics, alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible to have a breakdown of which utterances are used the most?

I'd like to save that information in order to further extend and improve the list of utterances mapped to each intent.

From Amazon Alexa Measure dashboard I can see a breakdown of intents but not utterances.

Is this a limitation of the dashboard or is the data not returned by the API at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Alexa does not give us information on what utterances the user asked. It only maps the utterances to the specific intent.

One possible solution would be to create a custom slot and a slot type and have all the utterance in the slot type and have an utterance like {slot} in the intent.

This way the utterance will be sent in the slot value to your back-end API which you can use for measuring.